# Gloss function `animate` doesnt seem to be doing anything

Tags: haskell, gloss

I am tying to create a simple animation using `haskell` gloss. I want that at the first 4 seconds, every rectangle will change its color to a darker one. The problem is that after a relatively long time of linking, nothing really happens -

[image]

All rectangles appear and they don't change color

This is the following code i used -

```
window :: Display
window = InWindow "Simon" (width, height) (offset, offset)

background :: Color
background = black

data SimonGame = Game {
    rectangleGreen::Picture, 
    rectangleRed::Picture,
    rectangleBlue::Picture,
    rectanglYellow::Picture
} deriving Show

initialState :: SimonGame
initialState = Game
  { rectangleGreen = translate (-100) (0) $ color green $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
    rectangleRed = translate (100) (0) $ color red $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
    rectangleBlue = translate (0) (100)  $  color blue $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
    rectanglYellow = translate (0) (-100)  $  color yellow $ rectangleSolid 60 60
  }

render :: SimonGame -> Picture 
render game = pictures
              [ rectangleGreen game,
                rectangleRed game,
                rectangleBlue game,
                rectanglYellow game
              ]

updateBoard :: Float-> SimonGame -> SimonGame 
updateBoard 1.0 game = game { 
                              rectangleGreen = translate (-100) (0) $ color (dark green)  $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleRed = translate (100) (0) $ color red $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleBlue = translate (0) (100)  $  color blue $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectanglYellow = translate (0) (-100)  $  color yellow $ rectangleSolid 60 60
                            }
updateBoard 2.0 game = game { 
                              rectangleGreen = translate (-100) (0) $ color green $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleRed = translate (100) (0) $ color (dark red) $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleBlue = translate (0) (100)  $  color blue $rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectanglYellow = translate (0) (-100)  $  color yellow $rectangleSolid 60 60
                            }                         
updateBoard 3.0 game = game {
                              rectangleGreen = translate (-100) (0) $ color green $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleRed = translate (100) (0) $ color red $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleBlue = translate (0) (100)  $  color (dark blue) $rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectanglYellow = translate (0) (-100)  $  color yellow $rectangleSolid 60 60
                            }
updateBoard 4.0 game = game { 
                              rectangleGreen = translate (-100) (0) $ color green $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleRed = translate (100) (0) $ color red $ rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectangleBlue = translate (0) (100)  $  color blue $rectangleSolid 60 60,
                              rectanglYellow = translate (0) (-100)  $  color (dark yellow) $rectangleSolid 60 60
                            }
updateBoard _ game = game

main :: IO ()
main = animate window background frame
  where
    frame :: Float -> Picture
    frame seconds = render $ updateBoard seconds initialState
```

Comment: My guess is that the pattern matches on `1.0`, `2.0`, etc. are failing and you're matching on the `_` case.  Maybe temporarily make the `_` case the same as the `4.0` case and see if that behaves differently.  Do you know about the pitfalls of comparing floating point numbers?

Comment: [What every computer scientist should know about floating-point arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html). (But the problem with your code is actually more fundamental than the typical float problems.)

Comment: Another thing: please don't write such repetitive code as in `updateBoard`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Never equality-check on floating point numbers*. (Or, if you do, always assume the result may be `False` even if the numbers are conceptually equal.)

In your case, that's not even conceptually the case, because `animate` is called on some finite points in time; why would these include any exact integral number of seconds?

One simple way to get around this is to look up the *rounded-to-whole-seconds* time.

```
updateBoard :: Int -> SimonGame -> SimonGame 
updateBoard 1 game = game { ... }
updateBoard 2 game = game { ... }
...

main = animate window background frame
  where
    frame :: Float -> Picture
    frame seconds = render $ updateBoard (floor seconds) initialState
```

Comment: Guards can also result in an acceptable looking solution.  `updateBoard t game | t < 1 = ... ; | t < 2 = ... ; | t < 3 = ... ; | t < = 4 ... ; | otherwise = ...`.